# Access array variable in session (CodeIgniter)

Tags: codeigniter

I have an array called config.  I'm trying to echo a variable from the array in the session.

I've tried:

```
echo $this->session->userdata('config['item']');
```

but it doesn't work. What's wrong with my syntax here?  I've print_r'd my session and the items are in the config array.  I've also tried:

```
echo $this->session->userdata("config['item']");
```

I get no errors this time, but no data either.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If config is an array . And item is string name of what you want to get from config then

```
echo $this->session->userdata($config['item']);
```

or

```
echo $_SESSION[$config['item']];
```

If config is an array inside session you should first get it.

```
$tmp = $this->session->userdata('config');
echo $tmp['item'];
```

or

```
echo $_SESSION['config']['item']
```

Sorry for my english.

Comment: why do i get undefined index whenever i do `$abc = $this->session->userdata('datauser');
echo $abc['ID_NUM'];`

Answer (score 9):

If you want to use the session array, use the variable, not the function:

```
echo $this->session->userdata['user_data']['item'];
```

If you want to write:

```
$this->session->userdata['user_data']['item'] = 'value';
$this->session->userdata['other_data']['other'] = 'value2';
$this->session->sess_write();
```

This allows you to edit values in array just like you do with $_SESION['user_data']['avatar'] = $avatar, with 'only' one extra line and only using CI library.

Answer (score 0):

Always escape your string it should be this way:

```
echo $this->session->userdata('config[\'item\']');
```

Comment: Yeah, I realized I had a quoting issue.  But this yields no data even though I can print_r it.

Comment: then u must see this http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html how to access ur config vars

Comment: The config array is in my userdata.  Could the two be colliding?