# CodeIgniter Session syntax

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can someone quickly help me out with CodeIgniter's syntax. I need to access an array I stored in the session's userdata and I cant figure out the proper syntax.

```
<?php echo $this->session->userdata['user_session']['first_name']; ?>
```

gives me this error:

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

All of the answers given in this Question dont work: 
[Access array variable in session (CodeIgniter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760848/access-array-variable-in-session-codeigniter)

Comment: `var_dump($this->session->userdata);` and read the error message carefully (you will wonder but it's output so that you could read it)

Comment: please show us the output of var_dump($this->session->userdata);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the proper syntax. Well, at least one way to go about it. @Matt GrubB was the closest and put me on the right track.

```
$temp_session = $this->session->userdata('user_session');
echo $temp_session->first_name;
```

Since `userdata` is an object full of info created when I query my database, the easiest way to access the data is to take it and put it in another temporary array. You then have to stab it. I kept stumbling by trying to do `$this->temp_session->first_name` or something of the like.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get session data:

```
echo $this->session->userdata('first_name');
```

Answer (score 0):

Been a while since I've worked in Codeigniter, but if I can remember correctly, when you store an array like you've stated, you'd call it like this:

```
$this->session->userdata("user_session")['first_name'];
```

Let me know if that works?

Or you can store that data to a variable, and call the array that way. Like such:

```
$data = array("bar" => "the_value");
$this->session->set_userdata("foo", $data);
$foo = $this->session->userdata("foo");
echo $foo["bar"]; //Outputs the_value
```

Let me know if that helped.

However, just to let you know.. Normally, storing the session data goes as follows:

```
$this->session->set_userdata("first_name", "value");
```

Really no need to go and set your own array inside of userdata, because that's generally what the userdata array is for.